# How to pass extra parameters to controller from Laravel route

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to handle basic validation of my API calls in the Laravel's routes. Here is what I want to achieve:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1/properties/'], function () {
     Route::get('purchased', 'PropertiesController@getPropertyByProgressStatus', function () {
       //pass variable x = 1 to the controller
     });

     Route::get('waiting', 'PropertiesController@getPropertyByProgressStatus', function () {
       //pass variable x = 2 to the controller
});
```

});

Long story short, depending on the segment of the URI after api/v1/properties/ I want to pass a different parameter to the controller. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work with the following route.php file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1/properties/'], function () {
    Route::get('purchased', [
        'uses' => 'PropertiesController@getPropertyByProgressStatus', 'progressStatusId' => 1
    ]);
    Route::get('remodeled', [
        'uses' => 'PropertiesController@getPropertyByProgressStatus', 'progressStatusId' => 1
    ]);
    Route::get('pending', [
        'uses' => 'PropertiesController@getPropertyByProgressStatus', 'progressStatusId' => 3
    ]);
    Route::get('available', [
        'uses' => 'PropertiesController@getPropertyByProgressStatus', 'progressStatusId' => 4
    ]);
    Route::get('unavailable', [
        'uses' => 'PropertiesController@getPropertyByProgressStatus', 'progressStatusId' => 5
    ]);
});
```

and the following code in the controller:

public function getPropertyByProgressStatus(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

```
$action = $request->route()->getAction();
print_r($action);
```

Pretty much the $action variable is going to let me access the extra parameter that I passed from the route.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do it directly in the controller and receiving the value as a parameter of your route:

First you need to specify the name of the parameter in the controller.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1/properties/'], function ()
{
    Route::get('{parameter}', PropertiesController@getPropertyByProgressStatus');
```

In this way, the getPropertyByProgressStatus method is going to receive this value, so in the controller:

```
class PropertiesController{
....
public function getPropertyByProgressStatus($parameter)
{
    if($parameter === 'purchased')
    {
        //do what you need
    }
    elseif($parameter === 'waiting')
    {
        //Do another stuff
    }
....
}
```

I hope it helps to solve your issue.

Take a view for this courses: [Learn Laravel](https://www.udemy.com/laravel-5-course-learn-php-laravel/?couponCode=forum) or [Create a RESTful API with Laravel](https://www.udemy.com/laravel-5-php-framework-agile-and-practical-php-restful-api/?couponCode=forum)

Best wishes.

----------- Edited ---------------
You can redirect to the route that you want:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1/properties/'], function () {
     Route::get('purchased', function () {
       return redirect('/api/v1/properties/purchased/valueToSend');
     });

     Route::get('waiting', function () {
       return redirect('/api/v1/properties/waiting/valueToSend');
     });

    Route::get('purchased/{valueToSend}', PropertiesController@getPropertyByProgressStatus);
     });

    Route::get('waiting/{valueToSend}', PropertiesController@getPropertyByProgressStatus);
     });
});
```

The last two routes response to the redirections and send that value to the controller as a parameter, is the most near that I think to do this directly from the routes.

Comment: Yea, the question is how do I do that in the route? As I mentioned in the question: "I'm trying to handle basic validation of my API calls in the Laravel's routes". thanks

Comment: Well, basically you are doing it in the route, check that you are receiving a parameter and sending it to the controller. It is not useful for you? Please give some more details to undertand why it does not work. Best wishes.

PS: You can return a redirection to another route. CHeck the response (edited)

Comment: Still not what I wanted to get. Take a look at this code: Route::get('api/v1/properties/purchased', 'PropertiesController@getPropertyById', function ($variableX) {}); How do I modify $variableX to pass 1 for instance?